# Encryption of OpenCV VideoWriter output

Tags: c++, opencv, video, encryption, ffmpeg

In an embedded project I was using opencv cv::VideoWriter to store frames as video files, also utilising lossless compression codecs (e.g.Lagarith). Now I have the requirement to encrypt the video files before storing them.

1. Is it possible to get the encoded output from cv::VideoWriter so that an encryption step can be applied before writing the frame to disk?
2. Alternatively, is it possible to make cv::VideoWriter output to a custom output stream? That way encryption steps can be applied on the stream.
3. If neither of above is possible then is there an alternative to cv::VideoWriter that I can use to get the video format encoding done?

The end requirement is to write encrypted files which, after only a decryption step, become video files compatible with standard video players.

Comment: 1+2. No (just look at the [docs](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/dd/d9e/classcv_1_1VideoWriter.html#details) and it should be evident). 3. Use whatever [backend](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/d0/da7/videoio_overview.html) OpenCV is currently using -- probably ffmpeg.

Comment: Thanks for the input! I have looked a little into ffmpeg usage and what I want to do does not seem very straightforward with my limited knowledge. Writing a frame boils down to call to: `av_interleaved_write_frame` and that takes a structure of type AVFormatContext. This structure contains a member `filename`. So before calling `av_interleaved_write_frame` the structure must be populated with a filename. It does not look to me that the av_interleaved_write_frame would provide me its output before writing it to the preset file. Any help regarding what to use in ffmpeg would be much appreciated!

Comment: Here is a discussion from 2008, but unfortunately all the links provided as solution are broken: http://lists.ffmpeg.org/pipermail/ffmpeg-devel/2008-January/047321.html